# How to deal with async requests in Marionette?

Tags: marionette

I am trying to fill in an ItemView in Marionette with the combined results of 2 API requests.

```
  this.standings = App.request('collection:currentStandings');
  this.userInfo = App.request('model:userInfo');
  this.standings.each(function(s) {
    if (s.currentUser) {
      s.set('alias', this.userInfo.alias);
      s.set('imageURL', this.userInfo.imageURL);
    }
  });
  userInfoView = new LeagueBar.UserInfo({ collection: this.standings });
```

The problem is, the combination never happens because the requests have not been fulfilled before I try to combine them.

I know I probably need to add a promise for each request, but I haven't been able to find a clean way to do it. I could make 'collection:currentStandings' and 'model:userInfo' return promises, however, they are currently used in many other parts of the code, so I would have to go back and add .then()s and .done()s all over the code base where they weren't required before.

Any ideas or suggestions?

EDIT:

I have currently solved this in a less-than-ideal way: I created a template/view for the alias and a template/view for the imageURL and kept the template/view for the standings info. This doesn't seem like the best way and I'm interested to know the right way to solve this problem.

here are the two requests I am trying to combine:

```
Models.CurrentStandings = App.Collection.extend({
    model: Models.PlayerStandings,
    url: function() { return 'leagues/' + App.state.currentLeague + '/standings'; },
    parse: function(standings) {
        return _.map(standings, function(s) {
            if (s.memberId == App.user.id)
                s.currentUser = true;
            return s;
        });
    }
});

App.reqres.setHandler('collection:currentStandings', function() {
    weekStandings = new Models.CurrentStandings();
    weekStandings.fetch({ success: function(data){ console.log(data); }});
    return weekStandings;
});

Models.UserInfo = App.Model.extend({
    url: 'users/me'
});

App.reqres.setHandler('model:userInfo', function(options) {
    myuser = new Models.UserInfo();
    myuser.fetch(options);
    return myuser;
});
```

Comment: It would be helpful to show one of your `request` callbacks. I'd like to see how your handling the async server request there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 solutions which based on your dependencies among views can be selected:

1. You can create views which are handling 'change' event of Models.UserInfo and when the data is ready (Change/Reset event raised) re-render the content. It is probably your solution.
2. If you are looking for a solution which should not create instance of  LeageBar.UserInfo until both Models.CurrentStanding and Models.UserInfo are ready, you **have to** return the result of fetch function, so you may remove calling fetch from setHandlers and use them as following:

   ```
   this.standings = App.request('collection:currentStandings');
   this.userInfo = App.request('model:userInfo');
   var that=this;
   that.standings.fetch().done(function(){
       that.userInfo.fetch().done(function(){
           that.standings.each(function(s) {
               if (s.currentUser) {
                   //....
               }
           });

           userInfoView = new LeagueBar.UserInfo({ collection: that.standings });
   });
   ```